# Account registration on mobile application

Tags: android, ios, rest, mobile

I'm working on a hybrid mobile application for both android / iOS, which mainly send requests to a restful server using an access token for authentication / authorization.

However, not sure how to implement the account creation part, would it be ok to allow a POST request with an email address / password to register a user? Something like `POST /signup` (Of course using https, email verification etc).

Or is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is essentially how classic signup works on most mobile apps. POST email/password to a signup URL and receive an access token in the response.

If you want to get fancy, you can incorporate a secret app token so the request can be signed, and the server can theoretically guarantee the request came from your own app and no-one else's. The problem though is a "secret" in the client is not really a secret, anyone has access to the compiled code and the requests being made. (Twitter, for example, has [encountered this problem](http://appadvice.com/appnn/2013/03/as-secret-keys-leak-twitter-needs-to-decide-what-to-do-about-third-party-apps).)

There's also single-sign on via Twitter, Google, Facebook, etc. in which case you can just upload the access token after user authenticates on the device. Some apps also request a phone number instead of email, and then verify by SMS (which is automatic if the app can read SMS), e.g. WhatsApp.